# Is there a way to perform the GUI mode 'Validate' on the command line in JMeter?

Tags: validation, command-line, jmeter

I have many JMeter Web tests that I need to validate and it's laborious to open each test, right click and Validate on each one.
Is there any way to run the single thread, single execution 'Validate' test on the command line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently it is not something you cannot trigger via command line, however you can achieve the same using JMeter Properties, i.e. instead of hard-coding number of threads in [Thread Groups](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group), sleep time in [Timers](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#timers), percent execution in the [Throughput Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Throughput_Controller), etc. use [__P() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P) instead like:

```
${__P(threads,100)}
```

or

${__P(loops,50)}

[image: JMeter Thread Group properties parameterization]

So by default your Thread Group will run 100 virtual users for 50 loops. However you will be able to [override](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#override) the values using `-J` command-line argument like:

```
jmeter -Jthreads=1 -Jloops=1 -n -t test.jmx -l result.jtl
```

This way the test will execute with 1 virtual user and 1 loop. You can manipulate other properties using similar approach. Check out [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization) for more details.

Comment: Thanks - is there any easy way to detect if the test has thrown any errors other than parsing the jtl?

Comment: You can add a [JSR223 Listener](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Listener) to your test plan and use the following code: `if (prev.isSuccessful()) {println('!!!!!!!!!!!! ERROR OCCURRED !!!!!!!!!!!!')}`. You can also consider using [Taurus](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/taurus-new-star-test-automation-tools-constellation) tool as a wrapper for your JMeter test, it has powerful [Pass/Fail](http://gettaurus.org/docs/PassFail/) criteria subsystem  which will return non-zero exit code for the task which you can check as `%errorlevel%` on Windows or `$?` on Linux

Comment: My tests are currently setup to run for a duration - how can I turn that off and run for a single loop instead?

Comment: If you set Loop Count to 1 using the above approach JMeter will stop after 1st iteration